# CSS stylesheet scoped to a single svg tag

Tags: css, html, svg

I have a web page with two or more SVG tags.  Each SVG tag contains a style tag block containing the CSS styles for the given SVG element.  Unfortunately, it appears that these stylesheets bleed into the global styles.  For example, setting the style for class 'x1' on the first SVG element will cause the style for class 'x1' on the second SVG to be set as well.  I would like to be able to set different styles for each specific SVG document.  Is this possible?

Comment: The accepted answer no longer works, here is a modern solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932376/4137472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once browsers support it, you want [`<style scoped>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped). That means Firefox 21 or later, or Chrome 19 or later (but you need to enable it in chrome://flags).

Comment: Update: According to a link on caniuse.com, this has been removed from the spec - https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552

Comment: This is no more working (used to work under flags), here is a working Shadow DOM solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/62932376/4137472

Answer (score 2):

#### Use Shadow DOM

If you don't need to support IE and other ancient browsers, create a Custom Element, that will put all it's children into it's Shadow Root.

```js
class SVGContainer extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'});
    shadowRoot.append(...this.childNodes);
  }
}

customElements.define('svg-container', SVGContainer);
```

```html
<style>#svg-text { fill: red; }</style>
<label id="html-text">I am HTML</label>
<svg-container>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 30">
    <style>#html-text { color: red; }</style>
    <text id="svg-text" y="20">I am SVG</text>
  </svg>
</svg-container>
```

Comment: This code snippet is just showing black text for me. Chrome 98.0.4758.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @GusTButt That's correct, if there was a mistake, the text would be red.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `id`s to distinguish elements from each other.then configure **CSS** styles to affect certain elements. for browser support, its a common practice to put your **CSS** styles into separate files or `<style>` sections.